# Track traffic from Facebook

Tags: facebook, hyperlink, facebook-like

I want to know if there is a way to figure out where the traffic from Facebook came from.

Actually I want to know the users that posted a link to my page.

Each link from facebook has 4 arguments : *u* (my url), *h*, *enc* and *s*.

I think that argument '*h*' has something to do with that.

I don't want to know which user opened the URL! I want to know the profile where the user found the link to my page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can´t find out which user opened the URL, unless you authorized the user with an App on that website.

Edit: Sorry, i misread the part about the user. But of course it´s not possible to find out who posted it either. That would not even be possible with any authorization.

Comment: No, I don't want to know which user opened the URL! I want to know  the profile where the user found the link to my page.

Comment: This does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be a comment.

Comment: @VVK: This is a correct answer to the question, saying that it's not possible.

Comment: oh, i misread the part about the user, i will edit my answer.